# IIS 7.5 FTP Extensibility in .NET and C#

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I'm trying to create a custom authentication provider for FTP in IIS 7.5 using .NET and C#.

I have been following this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2011/06/30/how-to-create-an-authentication-provider-for-ftp-7-5-using-blogengine-net-s-xml-membership-files.aspx, and have a basic FTP Authentication class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Web.FtpServer;

namespace FtpTest
{
    public class FtpAuthentication : BaseProvider, IFtpAuthenticationProvider, IFtpRoleProvider, IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider
    {
        public bool AuthenticateUser(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName, string userPassword, out string canonicalUserName)
        {
            canonicalUserName = "";
            return true;
        }

        public bool IsUserInRole(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName, string userRole)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public string GetUserHomeDirectoryData(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine locally on my machine where the project is built .NET 4.5 using IIS 8.5.

From what I understand, for FTP Extensibility to work on IIS 7.5, the project version needs to be .NET 3.5 (i.e. earlier than .NET 4):

Taken from [IIS FTP 7.5: custom extension assembly gets cached and won't be updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370878/iis-ftp-7-5-custom-extension-assembly-gets-cached-and-wont-be-updated): "FTP service is configured to load my extension component written using .NET 3.5 - because it ONLY accepts .NET 2.0 runtime; if you implement extension in runtime 4 it simply won't run"

The issue I have is that when I change the project's target framework from .NET 4.5 to .NET 3.5, the Microsoft.Web.FtpServer dll (which I extend) still has indirect references to .NET 4 framework assemblies (so my code won't compile). When looking at the properties view of the Microsoft.Web.FtpServer reference, the runtime version is v2.0.50727 so I don't see why there are .NET 4 framework references.

I've tried quite a few ways of resolving this issue including getting an earlier file version of the Microsoft.Web.FtpServer dll from another machine running IIS 7.5, including this in my machine's GAC and updating the reference but with no success.

I understand this would should work fine on Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8 or later if it works on my local machine as a .NET 4 project, but it needs to work on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.

Has anybody else come across this issue or have any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Which references are they?  Have you changed all your references to the 3.5 versions in your referenced assemblies?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in the end I managed to resolve this issue by following the steps in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298577/visual-studio-2010-reference-assemblies-targeting-higher-framework-version